# joomla database select and insert query

Tags: mysql, joomla

i am trying to insert another info to joomla (2.5.7) database after user is registered. The user chooses his usergroup and I want the insertion to happen only when the user is in a specific group. So I am trying to use this code to get the group data from the databse first to be used in the insert query. Now it is just a testing ground, later this retrieved value be used in if statement.

This is the code:

```
function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
    {
    if ($isnew && $success) {
  $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
  $query = "SELECT #__k2_users.group FROM #__k2_users WHERE userID = ".$user['id'];
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $group = $db->loadResult();

  $db->setQuery( 'INSERT INTO #__user_profiles (ordering) VALUES ('.$group.')' );
  $db->query();
   if (!$db->query()) 
   {
    throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
   }  
  }
    return $this->onAfterStoreUser($user, $isnew, $success, $msg);
}
```

and this is the error I am getting upon the failed registration:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 SQL=INSERT INTO std13_user_profiles (ordering) VALUES ()
```

If I read it correctly, it means that the select statement is not returning anything but why? Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

```
 if ($isnew && $success) {
  $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
  $userId   = JArrayHelper::getValue($user, 'id', 0, 'int');
  $query = "SELECT #__k2_users.group FROM #__k2_users WHERE userID = ".$userId;
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $group = $db->loadResult();


    $query2 = "INSERT INTO #__user_profiles (ordering) VALUES ('".$group."')";
    $db->setQuery($query2);
    $db->query();
   if (!$db->query()) 
   {
    throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
   }  
  }
```

with this code, I don't get any errors and the user is registered and the values are inserted. However the $group is always 0 and based on the value is only 1 or 3 in k2_users table, I am guessing that it returns nothing. I think it may be because the registered user is not stored in the databse yet and it doesn't have his ID yet to look for the group?

UPDATE2:

```
if ($isnew && $success) {

    $count = JRequest::getVar('gender');
    if($count == 3) {

    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $alias = $user['name'];
    $table = array(
    ' '=>'-', 'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'C'=>'C', 'c'=>'c', 'C'=>'C', 'c'=>'c',
    'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
    'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
    'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'ě'=>'e', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
    'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
    'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
    'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
    'ÿ'=>'y', 'R'=>'R', 'r'=>'r', " "=>'-', '"'=>'-'
);
    $string = strtr($alias, $table);
    $alias_low = strtolower($string);
    $query = "INSERT INTO #__menu (menutype, title, alias,  path, link, type, published, level, component_id, access) VALUES ('stavebnici','".$user['name']."','".$alias_low."','".$alias_low."',
    'index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=user&id=".$user['id']."&task=user','component',1,1,10012,1)";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
   if (!$db->query()) 
   {
    throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
   }
   }  
  }
```

OKAY! I got it working so now I can insert new menu every time a user is created, however th activation link is not created and the registration says that it failed. This is the error:

```
Duplicate entry '0-1-vojtech-plesner-' for key 'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language' SQL=INSERT INTO std13_menu (menutype, title, alias, path, link, type, published, level, component_id, access) VALUES ('stavebnici','Vojtěch Plešner','vojtech-plesner','vojtech-plesner', 'index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=user&id=2789&task=user','component',1,1,10012,1)
```

The client_id, parent_id and language have values of 1,1 and * abd they are in all the rows so why is it saying it is duplicate?

Comment: what is the value of `$group` .

Comment: i want the $group to return the result from the select query it should be a number 1 or 3

Comment: try to debug the code from the beginning of this function.

Comment: @Tornado I have edited my question with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update that query to 2.5 style.

http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html

is a good article.

You definitely seem to be missing
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

not to mention that you are using & for an object. That usage will generate strict errors.

Comment: thank you! you were correct! It was in the database definition and execution of query! Now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one query:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO #__user_profiles (ordering)
    SELECT #__k2_users.group 
    FROM #__k2_users 
    WHERE userID = " . user['id']
    ";
```

But doesn't `#__user_profiles` have other columns like the user id?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that would be doable but as I have written I will use the value from the select statement in a if condition which will execute the insertion or wont if the if is not passed. I am using the user_profiles table just to trry the code out.

Answer (score -1):

Also You can do it with one query:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO #__user_profiles (ordering)
    SELECT "YOURJOOMLADBPREFIX"_k2_users.group 
    FROM "YOURJOOMLADBPREFIX"_k2_users 
    WHERE userID = " . user['id']
    ";
```